# JAVA Date in sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, date

I got a Date type of value "2007-1-1" but  after saved, "01  1 2007 12:00AM" instead it in sqlserver. How to save "2007-1-1" in sqlserver?
Thank you all.

Comment: Show us the table definition (`create table ...`)  and your Java code.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't sound like you've got a problem at all. You're saving a *date*, not a string. How that happens to be represented when you fetch it back *and convert it to text* is irrelevant. You should view the value as a date, not a piece of text. At that point, you're fine. If you want to convert that date into text in a specific format, that's an entirely separate operation.

(Note that you should try to avoid string conversions where possible - for example, always use appropriate parameters in prepared statements instead of putting the values directly into SQL, and don't blindly convert all values to strings before use when using the returned results.)

Comment: Thank you ! When I use method DateUtils.parseDate(value, datePattern); It throws java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse the date: 01  1 2007 12:00AM

Comment: @user1484878: Why are you parsing it to start with? You should be fetching it from the result set as a `Date` rather than as a string.